# Python Selenium Execute Script always returns None

Tags: python, selenium

I don't understand why my python script prints"None" after executing my script:

```
script2="""
      function blablatet(){
        return "BLABLABLA7";
      } blablatet();
       """
executed = driver.execute_script(script2)
print(executed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
script2="""
      function blablatet(){
        return "BLABLABLA7";
      } 
      return blablatet();
       """
executed = driver.execute_script(script2)
print(executed)
```